# Kendo dropdownlist doesn't bind the selected value when done through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

js fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/9xj8huj9/1/

```
$("#Instrument").data("kendoDropDownList").bind('change',function (dataItem) {
        alert("Data Binded");
    });
```

Somehow, when the value of the dropdownlist is set dynamically when the button is clicked, data isn't binded.

Any idea how to bind the data here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the `change` event

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90yyfunr/)